# Good predictive models for a linear minimum bound?

Tags: predictive-models, extreme-value

Are there any good predictive models for a pattern like the left plot of the first figure? I'm trying to predict how long a file transfer takes (in seconds) according to its package size (in bytes). **I've been told that the best a file transfer can perform falls in the linear minimum bound across that plot, and anything above that means it's not doing its best. Is there any way to model this with that knowledge?**

[image: response against covariate]

So far I've applied log transformation to both of the variables (see right plot in first figure), and then used [multivariate adaptive regression spline (MARS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_adaptive_regression_splines). It predicted well according to the cross validated R^2 (0.953), but I wonder if there's a model that can capture that underlying knowledge about the minimum bound. Here's the 95% prediction interval using MARS and the model in the title of the plot (sorry it's a little cut off): [image: 95% prediction interval for MARS]